# JWT RSA Encryption - Would this be be slow with many requests?

Tags: encryption, rsa, jwt, public-key-encryption

I am considering using JSON web token with RSA encryption, but I'm worried about this being slow. My logic behind this is that TLS uses RSA encryption to exchange keys, but after that, AES encryption is used because Public/Private key decryption is slow.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like you're going in a dangerous direction. There are a few ways you can implement JWT:

- HMAC
- RSA *signing* not *encryption*
- ECDSA signing

Neither RSA encryption nor AES is the right tool for the job. [You want authentication, not encryption](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/08/you-wouldnt-base64-a-password-cryptography-decoded).

I'd recommend HMAC if you want speed. With a SHA2-family hash function; e.g. SHA-256.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a benchmark from a [Go implementation](https://github.com/pascaldekloe/jwt).

`BenchmarkHMACSign/HS256-12            500000          3421 ns/op
BenchmarkHMACSign/HS384-12            300000          4014 ns/op
BenchmarkHMACSign/HS512-12            300000          4131 ns/op
BenchmarkHMACCheck/HS256-12           200000          8737 ns/op
BenchmarkHMACCheck/HS384-12           200000          9506 ns/op
BenchmarkHMACCheck/HS512-12           200000          9634 ns/op
BenchmarkRSASign/1024-bit-12            2000        567073 ns/op
BenchmarkRSASign/2048-bit-12             500       2569703 ns/op
BenchmarkRSASign/4096-bit-12             100      14835903 ns/op
BenchmarkRSACheck/1024-bit-12          50000         35438 ns/op
BenchmarkRSACheck/2048-bit-12          20000         75855 ns/op
BenchmarkRSACheck/4096-bit-12          10000        204811 ns/op`